# MSChart - bar graph with multiple start and stop points

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart

I am hoping someone can help me with an issue setting points on a bar graph with multiple start and stop points along each series. Note the first and last bars each have multiple starting and ending points.

[image: sample bar chart]

Any tutorials or sample code would be greatly appreciated. sorry the image is so small.

Comment: I recommend using Google charts, instead (if you're building a web application).  Ref.  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Comment: At this point in time Google charts is not an option.

Comment: I have never used MS Charts but if you decide that you can use google charts, it's pretty easy with asp.net mvc, read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828548/google-combo-charts/12518997#12518997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are range bar charts

`chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;`

as always with MSchart, I'd recommend you take a look at the samples provided [HERE](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart). It has a section that demonstrate how to use RangeBar charts to achieve what you described.

Comment: I think this is a custom control. I am trying to do this with the ASP.net chart controls. in VB or C#.  thanks, still searching

Comment: RangeBar is supported by the web chart controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype.aspx). If you are not using the mschart, but some other charting framework, then you should remove the 'mschart' tag from it.

Comment: I am using .net 3.5, and it appears that this is not supported here. I plan to migrate soon, so I will look into this again in the coming weeks. thanks