# ASP MVC 3 - Chart from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, mschart

Using ASP MVC 3, I have created a viewmodel that I pass to a View in order to create a number of tables to display the data. However, I would also like to present some of the data in the form of chart/graph images using the Chart helper.

Is it possible to reuse the existing viewmodel for these Charts, or will I need to go through another MVC cycle just to create this Chart? I'm trying to prevent a return trip to the database just to get the same information that I already have on-hand in the View. The "database" that I'm hitting is actually an API that requires a expensive log-in, fetch, log-out cycle anytime I need to get this information.

It is not the "end of the world" if this is not possible, but it feels like there should be some slick way to make this happen that I'm just missing.

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you don't leave that view. That viewmodel is still available to you.

Comment: But is it possible to build the Chart image "in line" with the view? The fact that an img tag has a src attribute means that at minimum I will need to hit another Controller. Is it possible to pass the ViewModel BACK to a Controller for it to use and generate the image with?

Comment: As long as the controller is expecting to receive it there should be no problem.

Comment: How do I pass a model to a Controller via an img tag, though? I understand how to pass parameters via the URL in the src attribute like /Objects?Name=bla&Desc=MoreBla. Would I need to create a very long GET URL to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cache the results on the server. This does introduce a fair amount of complexity though. However, your question sounds like the definitive use case for caching application data.

[Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that should get you going if you can utilize ASP.NET's caching, if you choose to implement server side caching.

Comment: It looks like caching will be the way to go for me, and it doesn't look anywhere near as complex as I thought it'd be! This not only answers my question, but also answers one that I had in general about persisting objects/data to the server for periods of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is definitely possible to re-use the data from the tables and the viewmodel.

One approach would be to render the viewmodel into hidden fields in your view that are contained within a form.  You could then post this form to the server, which would bind it back to your viewmodel.

Sorry I can't be more specific, it is difficult without seeing the viewmodel and shape of the views.

Comment: There is no form associated with this View. Unless I'm doing this backward, the View simply has an img tag with a src attribute that is used to fetch the desired image. In this case, the image would be a dynamically generated Chart from some data. The only two solutions I can think of right now are simply getting all the data again in that request, or potentially creating a very long GET string using the ViewModel data and including that as the src attribute to the img tag.

Comment: Have you got an alias?  This is really similar to something earlier! Somehow you have to get your table data back to the server, be it either by a query string or a post. If you do it via query string, at least you can just hand that to the img tag and let the browser do the rest. If you do it with post, you will have to code the ajax call and handle the return image data yourself.

Comment: Another option might be to store the data in a cache server side that could provide faster access to the source data.

Comment: I think I will be going with the Caching option proposed below. I did consider creating a simple GET string for generating the graph, though that could lead to a lot of data sanitation headaches in the event that people try to pass things that they shouldn't to my graph.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but I recommend you use Google Charts.  They use HTML 5 and SVG and they are really nice looking.  See my answer here [Google Combo Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828548/google-combo-charts) where I show how to connect it to a database in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This answer is also quite useful, but I think it would take more time learning HTML 5 for me to make proper use of it. I'll be noting this for the future, though. Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually have to know any HTML 5 since it's all done for you.  You just have to know javascript and set the variables.  It's very easy.  Remember to upvote answers that you found helpful.

Comment: I tried to, but I'm still a bit short on Reputation! Thanks either way, and I'll try to revisit and upvote when I'm able to.